# How to show time updated at in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timestamp

Right now I have a function time_since

```
def time_since
    seconds = Time.now - self.updated_at
    if seconds < 15
        display = "Just Now"
    elsif seconds < 59.5    #less than 59.5 seconds
        display = seconds.round(0).to_s + "s"
    elsif seconds < (3600-30)    #less than 59.5 minutes
        display = (seconds/60).round(0).to_s + "m"
    elsif seconds < (86400-1800)     #less than 23.5 hours
        display = (seconds/3600).round(0).to_s + "h"
    elsif seconds < 86400*2    #less than 2 days
        display = "Yesterday"
    elsif seconds < 86400*7    #less than 1 week
        display = self.updated_at.strftime("%A")
    else                      #more than 1 week
        mon = self.updated_at.month
        day = self.updated_at.day.to_s  
        display = day + convert_month_number_to_month_name(mon).to_s
    end

    return display
end
```

And I want to be able to hover over this and have it display the exact updated_at timestamp. Is there a gem I can use easily to do this?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words

Comment: @anonymousxxx linked something great which is basically what you have implemented there. But more so, is your question how to display one text, but then add hover text? There are gems/libraries that give fancy tools for that, but you can also look up some basic javascript to get a hover event, or just use a `title` which often shows on hover on web browsers.

Comment: This is all awesome, but now I'm getting an error: undefined method `distance_of_time_in_words'. Do I need to include something new to access that method

Comment: `distance_of_time_in_words` is an ActionView Helper and should be called from the View.

Comment: you either need to call the `distance_of_time_in_words` from a view, or add the module `include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper` to your model

Comment: Oh ok! I was calling Object.distance_of_time_in_words on accident.

Comment: However, the title will not show the full timestamp for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I ended up using this:

```
<span title=<%= Object.updated_at.localtime.asctime.split.join('-') %>>
     <%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(Object.updated_at, include_seconds = true) %>
</span>
```

I couldn't get title to show more than the first word of the time so I joined it with dashes (even when I used strftime). This is functional and I'll clean it up later